# How to align img horizontally and vertically in a figure box?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

Here is my code, how can I align `img` in the `figure box`?

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sg80c4xo/)

```
<ul class="blocs">
    <!--product big-->
    <li class="product-big">
        <section>
            <h1>text</h1>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur elit. 
                Aliquam at porttitor sem. Aliquam erat volutpat.
            </p>
            <ul>
                <li>  text</li>
                <li> text</li>
                <li>
                    <figure>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/" alt="product"/>
                        </a>
                    </figure>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your css

```
img {
position: absolute;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This css will resize your image to fit in your container and then center it horizontally and vertically.

```
/* Image center */
figure {
    /* Figure: orange */
    border: 2px solid #da0;
}
figure a {
    /* Anchor (container): gray */
    /*
        The container is 300x300 here
        but you can change it to 
        whatever you want
    */
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    line-height: 300px;

    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;

    border: 2px solid #666;
}

figure img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

http://codepen.io/victmo/pen/ZbxjNg

**EDIT:** Based on your fiddle, try these code which follows the same principle:

```
.product-big{
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 624px ;
  height: 317px;
  background:black;
  color: white;
  margin: 10px 0;
}


/*
Layout: This will have description 
and fig side by side 
*/
.product-big section,
.product-big figure {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 317px;
  float:left;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.product-big figure {
    line-height: 317px; 
    /* 
    for vertical-align to work, it's 
    parent line-height has to be same 
    height as the container
    */
}

.product-big figure img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}




.product-big section h1{
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.product-big section p{
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}
```